# How to check Speed(performance) view engines [pug/ejs/html]

Tags: html, node.js, performance, pug, ejs

I'm trying to make Web-Server with Node.js.

First of my project using pug for view engine.

But, Web-Designer gives me html, but it's syntax is too different from pug.

So, I want to change my project as html or ejs. (I think ejs is similar to html)

---

(I don't know how to set view engine **~~.html**, so I use ejs)
(But I'm not sure this way is right, under paragraph)

First, I generate new repository with `express --no-view`.

I set view engine in `app.js` like under,

```js
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

---

Now, I have some question for speed(performance) between [EJS, PUG, pure HTML].

I think render speed is `HTML > EJS > PUG`, but I have no ideas for check this performance.

I need advice. Any Guess, Link, Answers can help me.

Thanks to read my question.

Comment: Simply, I want to use view engine as pure html/css/js in `views` folder. Guide for this is helpful too. Thanks.

Comment: HTML isn't a templating system. EJS and PUG are. If it's static html and performance is important use a webserver like nginx/httpd to deliver the content.  If you need pages to be dynamic templates, create a page in EJS and PUG and compare them for your metrics of "performance". What are you most concerned about performance wise? What are you doing in the templates? This is hard one to answer as it's specific to your use case.

Comment: @Matt Thanks. I understand. My web-server first designed with PUG, but web designer doesn't know about PUG syntax. so I change it to EJS, and I want to know what is different between PUG & EJS. It was performance speed that I have a question as soon as I see it.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

EJS : 900-1200 request per second
HTML: 6000 request per second and 12000 with some customizations

Long Answer:
I made a simple test and I've got with express about 6000 request in a second with pure HTML and got about 12000 request per second by storing the HTML in a variable and send it to the client and tried with ejs I've got 900-1200 request per second

But the results may change by the way your code works and how your html/ejs file is written could change the results